# How to configure Rails 5.1 System-Test to visit external site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

I started working with Rails 5.1 this week and I am now studying a new feature called System-Tests.

I created a new System-Test which looks like this:

```
# ~/p4/test/system/tkrprices_test.rb

require 'application_system_test_case'

class TkrpricesTest < ApplicationSystemTestCase
  test 'I should get prices' do
    visit '/'
    sleep 4
  end
end
```

On my Linux host I ran it with these shell commands:

```
mkdir ~/bin/
cd    ~/bin/
wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.34/chromedriver_linux64.zip
unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
export PATH=${HOME}/bin:$PATH
cd ~/p4/
bin/rails test:system
```

The above test works well: It starts a chromedriver browser, it does a visit '/' with no problem.
Then, it exits after 4 secnonds.

Next I added one line of syntax so that the test would visit '/' at https://www.google.com

```
# ~/p4/test/system/tkrprices_test.rb

require 'application_system_test_case'

class TkrpricesTest < ApplicationSystemTestCase
  test 'I should get prices' do
    Capybara.app_host = 'https://www.google.com'
    visit '/'
    sleep 4
  end
end
```

The above test does not visit '/' at 'https://www.google.com'

Instead it just brings up an empty-chromedriver-browser with this string loaded in the URL field:

```
data:,
```

For this Rails App my Gemfile looks like this:

```
ruby '2.4.2'
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails_12factor'
gem 'haml'          
gem 'haml-rails'    

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Heroku wants this:
# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
# end
```

About Capybara I see this:

```
dan@tkrapi:~/p4 $ grep capybara Gemfile.lock
    capybara (2.16.1)
  capybara (~> 2.13)
dan@tkrapi:~/p4 $ 
dan@tkrapi:~/p4 $
```

For chromedriver I see this:

```
dan@tkrapi:~/p4 $ chromedriver -v
ChromeDriver 2.34.522913 (36222509aa6e819815938cbf2709b4849735537c)
dan@tkrapi:~/p4 $ 
dan@tkrapi:~/p4 $
```

My question is, "How to configure Rails 5.1 System-Test to visit external site?"

Comment: What version of Capybara are you using, and have you changed any of Capybaras default configuration?  What you did should work correctly with the current versions.  Also, what version of Chrome are you using with chromedriver 2.34 ?

Comment: This app uses Rails 5.1.4, Capybara 2.16.1, chromedriver 2.34.522913, and the version of chrome is ... well I'm not using chrome. I am using chromium and it tells me: Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit)

Comment: Try rolling back to chromedriver 2.33 and/or using Chrome rather than chromium.  chromedriver 2.34 was updated to support Chrome v 63 - so it's possible you've found a bug in it.  One other thing to try would be calling `visit 'https://www.google.com/'` and seeing if that works which would narrow down the possible causes.

Comment: One other possibility, did you previously have the `chromedriver-helper` or equivalent installed?  If so try running `bundle exec chromedriver -v` and see if the version reported is what you expect.  The gems that manage chromedriver (and/or geckodriver) can leave stubs behind which get included into your PATH when running your tests and leave you running unexpected versions of chromedriver.

Answer (score 1):

`ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase` configures Capybara on the `setup` method, as seen [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/375a4143cf5caeb6159b338be824903edfd62836/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/system_testing/test_helpers/setup_and_teardown.rb). So the way around is to set your own in `ApplicationSystemTestCase` by defining `setup`:

```
class ApplicationSystemTestCase < ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase
  def setup
    super
    Capybara.configure do |config|
      config.run_server = false
      config.app_host = 'https://www.google.com'
    end
  end
end
```

Alternatively, if you don't need to set any other configuration, you can just set it as a constant:

```
class ApplicationSystemTestCase < ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase
  DEFAULT_HOST = "https://www.google.com"
end
```

Both ways, a test like the following will pass:

```
require "application_system_test_case"

class GoogleTest < ApplicationSystemTestCase
  test "visits google" do
    visit "/"

    assert_equal "https://www.google.com", Capybara.app_host
    page.assert_text "Google"
  end
end
```